# How can I scrape text based on a fields ID using WatiN?

Tags: c#, winforms, copy, web

I'm working on a program that will go to a website, and then copy and store the text of a specific field into memory. The field information on the webpage is shown as:

```
<div id="doc-original-text">
```

Using the following code I am able to select a textfield on a page and input my own text:

```
using (myIE) {
myIE.TextField(Find.ById("descr")).Value = txtbxMessage.Text; }
```

In that code I'm telling myIE instance to choose the TextField by it's ID. I am wondering if in a similar way I can tell myIE to find by the ID of a field the text that is already present and copy it into memory? Something like:

```
//made up theoretical code
using (myIE) {
string information = myIE.Text(Find.ByID("doc-original-text")).Copy.ToString();
```

I also tried using this code, though it was unsuccessful. I'm not sure the call for "TextField" is appropriate though?

```
using (myIE) {
myIE.TextField(Find.ById("doc-original-text")).ToString(); }
```

Comment: How about ..Find(By.Attribute("..") ?

Comment: I'm still uncertain how to implement it. For example the first part tells myIE what it's looking for "TextField". I don't know how I specify to find text, or how to copy it into memory.

Comment: Alsto, you could try ..(Find.ByValue(".."));

Comment: The value varies from entry to entry so I needed to be able to scrape based off of the fields container id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the WaitiN Test Recorder to try a few things out and was able to come up with a way in which I could scrape the text in the field under the ID 'doc-original-text'. Here is the code:

```
using (myIE)
        {
            //this loads the website
            myIE.GoTo(txtbxWebSite.Text);                
            //stores the text from the area on the site in a string called 'temp'
            string temp = myIE.Div(Find.ById("doc-original-text")).ToString();
            //displays the string scraped
            MessageBox.Show(temp); }
```